# Changing the backcolor/forecolor of a control in a different process

Tags: c#, winapi, process

I am trying to create an application in C# using which I need to change the BackColor/Forecolor of some specific controls in another process/application. For example I have few application running in my machine. When I run the new C# application (which does not have any UI), the backcolor/forecolor of few controls in other applications should be changed to the new colors which I set. And when I close the application, the colors should be reset to the original colors. I tried the SetTextColor, SetBkColor windows apis from gdi32 but they dont work. Could you suggest me how can I achieve this?

Note: The coordinates of the controls for which the colors need to be changed are already noted and I am using the WindowFromPoint api to get the handle of the control.

This is the code which I tried.

```
point = new Point(1340, 144);
IntPtr hWnd = DllImports.WindowFromPoint(point);//this is a button control in one of the applications
if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    IntPtr wDC = DllImports.GetDC(hWnd);
    int result = DllImports.SetBkMode(wDC, TRANSPARENT);
        int i = DllImports.SetTextColor(wDC, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Red));
        i = DllImports.SetBkColor(wDC, ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Yellow));
        result = DllImports.SetBkMode(wDC, OPAQUE);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code of what you tried?

Comment: "a control" is way too broad - not every visible entity is a window (which you can at least hope to target with such operation) and not every control with window will respect colors you try to set. Narrowing down the question to particular "control" and showing code that does  not work would make the question better.

Comment: @preciousbetine, I have updated the question with the code

Comment: A device context is just a set of settings used for rendering. Merely setting attributes on your copy doesn't magically change the appearance. You'd have to perform rendering of some sort to actually use your settings. And that gets lots the moment the target application decides to redraw its UI. You would really need to infiltrate the target process, and intercept [WM_CTLCOLOREDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit) and friends.

Comment: What you are trying to do is essentially not viable. Best to recognise that now

Comment: See following : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/SetBkColor.html

Comment: @jdweng The issue is not that the asker needs to invoke the function. They've already managed to do that. The issue is that simply calling this function for a control in another app, outside of its internal paint cycle, does not achieve the desired effect.

Comment: If you had the handle then you can use the code to change the background color.

Comment: @jdweng No. You'd need to be calling `SetBkColor` whilst painting the control, in response to `WM_PAINT`. The code here is outside the process and not executing whilst painting the control.